# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert at PromiEvent When calling variable function from the deployed contract variable

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain

I am new to blockchain and development and learning from the dapp university tutorial.
I have created a contract Todolist.sol

```
  pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

    contract TodoList{
        uint public taskCount = 0;
    }
```

and have deployed it using

```
var TodoList = artifacts.require("./TodoList.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TodoList);
};
```

Then in truffle compiler, i ran the codes as follows which were working

todoList = await Todolist.deployed()
todoList.address

but, This gave me an error

```
todoList.taskcount()
```

as  Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert    at PromiEvent

Comment: The line `todoList = await Todolist.deployed() todoList.address` is not a valid line of code in Javascript!! In addition to that, there is a missing `await` before `todoList.taskcount()`.

Comment: It was `todoList = await TodoList.deployed()` only and was working. i tried `takCount = await todoList.taskCount()` also